# How to Pack/Encrypt/Unpack/Decrypt a bunch of files in Java?

Tags: java, jsp, encryption, zip, archive

I'm essentially trying to do the following on a Java/JSP-driven web site:

- User supplies a password
- Password is used to build a strongly-encrypted archive file (zip, or anything else) containing a text file as well as a number of binary files that are stored on the server.  It's essentially a backup of the user's files and settings.
- Later, the user can upload the file, provide the original password, and the site will decrypt and unpack the archive, save the extracted binary files to the appropriate folder on the server, and then read the text file so the site can restore the user's old settings and metadata about the binary files.

It's the building/encrypting the archive and then extracting its contents that I'm trying to figure out how to do.  I really don't care about the archive format, other than that it is very secure.

The ideal solution to my problem will be very easy to implement, and will require only tried-and-tested libraries with free and nonrestrictive licenses (e.g. apache, berkeley, lgpl).

I'm aware of the TrueZIP and WinZipAES libraries; the former seems like massive overkill and I can't tell how stable the latter is... Are there other solutions out there that would work well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know how to create a zip file using the [java.util.zip](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) package, you can create a PBE [Cipher](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) and pass that to a CipherOutputStream or a CipherInputStream (depending on if you're reading or writing).

The following should get you started:

```
public class ZipTest {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
        String password = "password";
        write(password);
        read(password);
    }

    private static void write(String password) throws Exception {
        OutputStream target = new FileOutputStream("out.zip");
        target = new CipherOutputStream(target, createCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, password));
        ZipOutputStream output = new ZipOutputStream(target);

        ZipEntry e = new ZipEntry("filename");
        output.putNextEntry(e);
        output.write("helloWorld".getBytes());
        output.closeEntry();

        e = new ZipEntry("filename1");
        output.putNextEntry(e);
        output.write("helloWorld1".getBytes());
        output.closeEntry();

        output.finish();
        output.flush();
    }

    private static Cipher createCipher(int mode, String password) throws Exception {
        String alg = "PBEWithSHA1AndDESede"; //BouncyCastle has better algorithms
        PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray());
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(alg);
        SecretKey secretKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithSHA1AndDESede");
        cipher.init(mode, secretKey, new PBEParameterSpec("saltsalt".getBytes(), 2000));

        return cipher;
    }

    private static void read(String password) throws Exception {
        InputStream target = new FileInputStream("out.zip");
        target = new CipherInputStream(target, createCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, password));
        ZipInputStream input = new ZipInputStream(target);
        ZipEntry entry = input.getNextEntry();
        while (entry != null) {
            System.out.println("Entry: "+entry.getName());
            System.out.println("Contents: "+toString(input));
            input.closeEntry();
            entry = input.getNextEntry();
        }
    }

    private static String toString(InputStream input) throws Exception {
        byte [] data = new byte[1024];
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        int bytesRead = input.read(data);
        while (bytesRead != -1) {
            result.append(new String(data, 0, bytesRead));
            bytesRead = input.read(data);
        }

        return result.toString();
    } 
}
```

Comment: What software would the client use to decrypt the scrambled ZIP file?

Comment: @PP Don't think it would be possible to do that with this solution as the file is just an encrypted blob.  The OP indicated that he wanted to control the decryption/unpacking himself, not a 3rd party

Answer (score 4):

The answer is already given (use a cipher as Kevin pointed out), so I am only doing a suggestion about an important matter which seems to be missing in your topicstart: ensure that you're using `HTTPS` instead of `HTTP`. Otherwise one with a network sniffer would be able to get the user-supplied password from the packets. How to do it depends on the appserver in question. Best is to refer its documentation. If it is for example Apache Tomcat, then you can find everything in the [Tomcat SSL HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Though it may not be specific to your query I wonder if [truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) could be of use. Your webserver could create an encrypted container into which the zip file would be copied. The encrypted container could then be downloaded. Potentially a little messy however the encryption should be strong and the downloaded image could be mounted on a variety of operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

There are surely a few suggestions here on how to solve your problem, but I'm missing a very big BUT in the responses. You cannot fulfill both "password based" and "strong encryption" for any reasonable definition of "strong encryption".

Comment: That is not necessarily true.  If you can provide a pass phrase that gives you 256 or even 192 bits of entropy, you can feed that in to any appropriate block cipher

Comment: Exactly, "if you can ..." and in most real situations that's not practical. Estimates on the entropy of English (as a natural language) are as low as 0.6 bits/character, meaning that you'll need a 430 character long pass phrase for 256 bits of entropy and that's a little bit more than what I would normally understand as a password.

Comment: Well, sure, if you let people use English words as passwords.  Just put some simple restrictions -- e.g. require at least one capital letter and one special character -- and you gain a lot of entropy.